# Couldn't match LoggingT with NoLoggingT

Tags: haskell, logging, monad-transformers

I have a following monad transformer stack including the monad-logger transformer and I want to be able to turn off logging by a parameter.

I can see, there is the `NoLoggingT` type but I don't know how to make it work.

```hs
newtype MyApp a = MyApp
  { runApp :: StateT Direction (LoggingT IO) a
  }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState Direction, MonadLogger)

runMyApp :: Params -> MyApp a -> Direction -> IO (a, Direction)
runMyApp (Params _ True) app st = runFileLoggingT "log.log" (runStateT (runApp app) st)
runMyApp (Params _ False) app st = runNoLoggingT (runStateT (runApp app) st)
```

How to turn off logging in this example?

I can see the function `filterLogger` that could return always false in case of deactivating the logging but is there any solution with the `runNoLoggingT`?

Answer (score 2):

Your MyApp type is too concrete: it always includes LoggingT, so it always runs with logging enabled. You could give it a type parameter, and instantiate that type parameter either with LoggingT or NoLoggingT:

```
newtype MyApp log a = MyApp
  { runApp :: StateT Direction (log IO) a
  }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState Direction, MonadLogger)
```

Then `MyApp LoggingT` logs, and `MyApp NoLoggingT` doesn't log. A client who doesn't care which is used (most of your program, probably) will leave that type variable unspecified:

```
doSomething :: MonadLogger (log IO) => MyApp log Int
doSomething = undefined
```

They can call log functions, which will either do something or do nothing, depending on which newtype you use at the top level when running the app.

Comment: It does not work in my case, it does not typecheck:

`
newtype MyApp log a = MyApp
  { runApp :: StateT Direction (log IO) a
  }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState Direction, MonadLogger)

runMyApp :: MonadLogger log => Params -> MyApp log a -> Direction -> IO (a, Direction)
runMyApp _ _ _ = undefined
`

The type error is following: `Expected kind ‘(* -> *) -> * -> *’, but ‘log’ has kind ‘* -> *’`

EDIT: sorry for formatting but it can't be properly formatted in comment

Comment: Oh yeah, the constraint on that is wrong. Try writing a function without a type and ask GHCI what type it should have. It's kinda confusing to work out what it should be.

Comment: Hmmm, when I remove the constraint then I get errors on all the typeclasses in the deriving..
The error are on all the deriving typeclasses, the errors have a similar meaning:

No instance for (Functor (log IO))
    arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
  Possible fix:
    use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
      so you can specify the instance context yourself
• When deriving the instance for (Functor (MyApp log))

Comment: Tbh unable to write concrete type for this feels quite lacking to me.

Comment: I think the correct constraint is  `runMyApp :: MonadLogger (log IO) => ....`  no compiler with me right now, but can you check it?

Comment: @lsmor I think so too, but it's rather unsatisfying to have all these functions need to specify that IO is in the stack rather than just implicitly getting that from MyApp.

Comment: @amalloy well, the point is that from the definition of `MyApp` we get that `log` is a monad transformer (or something of the same kind) ,  but from the function signature, `log` is just a monad. There is no way to match this two.

Comment: @Ismor that constraint does not work, I will probably try to reach the package author and ask him about his intentions with those types.

Comment: @xbalaj what's the error? is it the same?. On the other hand, when you define `runMyApp` with `runNoLoggingT` and `runFileLoggingT`, your are defining exactly what's the type of your function, and based on the usagge of both, your function will have type `MyApp NoLogginT` and `MyApp LoggingT`. I think you should create two functions: One for each logging capacity, then use `monadLoggerLog` to retrive the logging function itself and pass to each of the previous functions.